# Seeking shapefile of entire United States Census Blocks

Tags: geospatial, census

I am looking for a shapefile of the United States census blocks (not block groups, blocks) for 2020/multiple years.

When I go to the census site for downloads, it either doesn't appear to have blocks (the ftp site, https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020/ and would still require downloading all 50 states and merging them) or it will only let me download by state (the web download site https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2020&layergroup=Blocks+%282020%29).

This seems like something that should exist, but I can't find it. The feature service version of it from ESRI doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Is it the case that shapefiles have an effective 2GB size limit? If true, then this would be the reason - the ZIP files alone for all states look to add to the 5-10 GB range.

Comment: I don't know if size is the problem, though that is a consideration, good thing to think about.

The faculty person who wanted the shapefile just downloaded them state by state from the census and merged them (took a while, which is why she wanted the already merged file). Apparently it works, so it is possible to have a file like that, it just isn't readily available.